# gitignore not unignoring specific bin folder

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I have this directory structure (simplified for illustration purposes):

```
parent
--directory1
----bin
--directory2
----bin
-directory3
----bin

... and so on
```

I would like all 'bin' directories to be ignored by Git, except for just one of them (directory2/bin).  I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
[Bb]in
!directory2/[Bb]in
```

This doesn't work either

```
[Bb]in
!parent/directory2/[Bb]in
```

I also tried this and it doesn't work:

```
[Bb]in
!parent/directory2/[Bb]in/*
```

Anyone know how I can get this to work?

Comment: Which directory is the root of your git repository, `parent` or the one `parent` is in?

Comment: @Jasper, the root is the one that parent is in. For example, root/parent/directory2.  Thanks.

Comment: What is the current situation, is it not ignoring anything or is the ignoring part working but can't you get the exception to work?

Comment: The ignoring part is working but I can't get the exception to work.

Comment: I replicated this problem as well as I could and I got both your first try (with the `.gitignore` in `parent`) and your second try (with `.gitignore` in the root) to work exactly as they should. I am afraid the problem isn't in something you aren't showing us (though I really wouldn't know in what...)

Comment: @Jasper, I was able to get this working by adding a .gitignore file in "directory2" with: "![Bb]in". I hadn't even thought about doing that until I saw your comment.  I still don't know why I wasn't able to skip the directory from the root .gitignore.  Can you add your comment as an answer below?  I'd like to mark is as the answer.

Comment: Have the same issue. Any ideas what could be the reason? Would like to unignore it in the root.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used git to create a local repository based on the information in your question. However, once I had done so, the problem you are describing didn't exist and I couldn't easily find a way to introduce the problem.

It worked with this `.gitignore` in `parent`:

```
[Bb]in
!directory2/[Bb]in
```

And it also worked with this `.gitignore` in the root:

```
[Bb]in
!parent/directory2/[Bb]in
```

It seems the problem is not in the structure you have given in the question, but I don't have any idea where it would be then or where to start looking...

Comment: I have faced the same issue, I have put in directory2 .gitignore with `[Bb]in` and all start working. However than I realized that I was using wrong wrong path, in my case structure is little bit complicate and I have done a mistake. I sure that you need to copy path from explorer and compare with the specified in gitignore, and remember that paths are case sensetive. My final solution `!ParentDirectory/ExternalPackages/**/Bin/*`.

Comment: Ok, my prev comment not working xD I have put `![Bb]in` in local folder and keep calm :)